# To prove that induced probability measure indeed defines a probability measure

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Given two measurable spaces $(Ω_1, B_1)$ and $(Ω_2, B_2)$, a measurable function T : $Ω_1 → Ω_2$ and P is a probability measure on $(Ω_1, B_1)$. $B_1$ & $B_2$ are respective sigma algebras. The induced probability measure Q on $(Ω_2, B_2)$ is defined by
$Q(A) = P(T^{−1}(A))$ for $A ∈ B_2$.
Show that Q(A) indeed defines a probability measure on $(Ω_2, B_2)$.

My try:
Basically there are three axioms to be verified and I am able to verify the first one & the third one but not the second one as shown below:
1. $Q(B) = P(T^{-1}(B)) \ge 0 $ (obvious)
3. For disjoint sets $B_i , i \ge1$, we have $Q(\cup B_i)$=$P(T^{-1}(\cup B_i))$ = $P(\cup T^{-1}(B_i))$ = $\Sigma_{i \ge 1} P(T^{-1}(B_i))$ = $\Sigma_{i \ge 1} Q(B_i)$

But for the second axiom we have to show that $Q(\Omega_2)=1$. So proceeding we have $Q(\Omega_2)= P(T^{-1}(\Omega_2))$. I am stuck here, how to show that $T^{-1}(\Omega_2)=\Omega_1$.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan I have included my own try in the question itself in the recent edit.

Comment: $T^{-1}(\Omega_2) = \{x \in \Omega_1 : T(x) \in \Omega_2\}$. Since $T$ is a map from $\Omega_1$ to $\Omega_2$, are there any points in $y \in \Omega_1$ such that $T(y) \notin \Omega_2$?

Comment: I have got the key. Since T maps whole of $\Omega_1$ to $\Omega_2$, so $T^{-1}(\Omega_2)$ will map to whole of $\Omega_1$ as follows. Each element of $\Omega_1$ is mapped to some set/subset of $\Omega_2$ and since we have the property that $T^{-1}(A \cup B) = T^{-1}(A) \cup T^{-1}(B)$, so we'll have that   $T^{-1}(\Omega_2)=\Omega_1$

Answer (score 0):

Echoing the hint from @Prahlad Vaidyanathan:

To show that $T^{-1}(\Omega_2) = \Omega_1$, we need to show every element in $T^{-1}(\Omega_2)$ is in $\Omega_1$, and vice versa (by the definition of equal sets).

The direction from $T^{-1}(\Omega_2)$ to $\Omega_1$ is trivial due to the definition $T^{-1}(\Omega_2) = \{ \omega_1 \in \Omega_1 \mid T(\omega_1) \in \Omega_2 \}$. Obviously, for every $\omega_1 \in T^{-1}(\Omega_2)$, $\omega_1 \in \Omega_1$.

To prove the other direction, suppose there exists $\omega \in \Omega_1$ such that $\omega \notin T^{-1}(\Omega_2)$. Since $T$ is a function, there exists a $\sigma = T(\omega) \in \Omega_2$, and therefore $\omega \in T^{-1}(\Omega_2)$. This is a contradiction and we can conclude that every $\omega \in \Omega_1$ also satisfies $\omega \in T^{-1}(\Omega_2)$.

From the above, $T^{-1}(\Omega_2) = \Omega_1$. Q.E.D.